# Replace cells in a column of dataframe with NA if the column name exceeds the value of that row in an adjacent column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with multiple columns. One of the columns is N_L which ranges between 1 to 5. I have 5 columns named e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4, and e_5. The values in the e_ columns is calculated from other columns in the dataframe. A sample of the data is provided:

```
> head (DATA)
  N_l S   OH  e_1 e_2  e_3   e_4   e_5 e_sum
1   3 9  3.6 14.6 2.6 -9.4 -21.4 -33.4   -47
2   3 9  3.6 14.6 2.6 -9.4 -21.4 -33.4   -47
3   4 12 4.8 21.8 9.8 -2.2 -14.2 -26.2   -11
4   4 12 4.8 21.8 9.8 -2.2 -14.2 -26.2   -11
5   4 12 4.8 21.8 9.8 -2.2 -14.2 -26.2   -11
6   5 15  6  29   17    5  -7    -19      25
7   5 15  6  29   17    5  -7    -19      25
```

The e_ columns are calculated based on the other columns in the main dataframe such that:

```
DATA$e_1 <- (((DATA$N_b-1)*DATA$S + 2*DATA$OH)/2) - (parapet + edge.dist + truck.width/2)
DATA$e_2 <- DATA$e_1 - 2*truck.width
DATA$e_3 <- DATA$e_2 - 2*truck.width
DATA$e_4 <- DATA$e_3 - 2*truck.width
DATA$e_5 <- DATA$e_4 - 2*truck.width
DATA$e_sum <- DATA$e_1 + DATA$e_2 + DATA$e_3 + DATA$e_4 +DATA$e_5
```

I would like to set the columns e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4, e_5 to "NA" or "0" if the value in column N_L is less >= than the column name e_1, e_2, etc.

For example for the example above I would like to have:

```
  N_l S   OH  e_1 e_2  e_3   e_4   e_5 e_sum
1   3 9  3.6 14.6 2.6 -9.4  NA    NA     7.8
2   3 9  3.6 14.6 2.6 -9.4  NA    NA     7.8
3   4 12 4.8 21.8 9.8 -2.2 -14.2  NA     15.2
4   4 12 4.8 21.8 9.8 -2.2 -14.2  NA     15.2
5   4 12 4.8 21.8 9.8 -2.2 -14.2  NA     15.2
6   5 15  6  29   17    5  -7    -19      25
7   5 15  6  29   17    5  -7    -19      25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach requiring no loops that relies on multiplication:

```
DATA[,4:8] <- DATA[,4:8] * +(matrix(1:5, byrow = TRUE, ncol = 5, nrow = nrow(DATA))
                              <= DATA$N_l)
DATA$e_sum <- rowSums(DATA[,4:8])
  N_l  S  OH  e_1  e_2  e_3   e_4 e_5 e_sum
1   3  9 3.6 14.6  2.6 -9.4   0.0   0   7.8
2   3  9 3.6 14.6  2.6 -9.4   0.0   0   7.8
3   4 12 4.8 21.8  9.8 -2.2 -14.2   0  15.2
4   4 12 4.8 21.8  9.8 -2.2 -14.2   0  15.2
5   4 12 4.8 21.8  9.8 -2.2 -14.2   0  15.2
6   5 15 6.0 29.0 17.0  5.0  -7.0 -19  25.0
7   5 15 6.0 29.0 17.0  5.0  -7.0 -19  25.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one slightly convoluted option

```
library(plyr)

DATA <- do.call(rbind.fill,apply(DATA,1, function(x) as.data.frame(t(x[c(1:(3+x[1]))]))))
DATA$e_sum <- rowSums(DATA[,4:8],na.rm=T)

> DATA 
  N_l  S  OH  e_1  e_2  e_3   e_4 e_5 e_sum
1   3  9 3.6 14.6  2.6 -9.4    NA  NA   7.8
2   3  9 3.6 14.6  2.6 -9.4    NA  NA   7.8
3   4 12 4.8 21.8  9.8 -2.2 -14.2  NA  15.2
4   4 12 4.8 21.8  9.8 -2.2 -14.2  NA  15.2
5   4 12 4.8 21.8  9.8 -2.2 -14.2  NA  15.2
6   5 15 6.0 29.0 17.0  5.0  -7.0 -19  25.0
7   5 15 6.0 29.0 17.0  5.0  -7.0 -19  25.0
```

---

Data:

```
DATA <- structure(list(N_l = c(3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L), S = c(9L, 
9L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 15L, 15L), OH = c(3.6, 3.6, 4.8, 4.8, 4.8, 
6, 6), e_1 = c(14.6, 14.6, 21.8, 21.8, 21.8, 29, 29), e_2 = c(2.6, 
2.6, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 17, 17), e_3 = c(-9.4, -9.4, -2.2, -2.2, 
-2.2, 5, 5), e_4 = c(-21.4, -21.4, -14.2, -14.2, -14.2, -7, -7
), e_5 = c(-33.4, -33.4, -26.2, -26.2, -26.2, -19, -19), e_sum = c(-47L, 
-47L, -11L, -11L, -11L, 25L, 25L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a `for` loop overwriting where `DATA$N_l < i`, assuming that e_1 - e_5 are at that place where they are now.

```
for(i in 1:5) {DATA[DATA$N_l < i,i+3] <- NA}
DATA$e_sum <- rowSums(DATA[4:8], na.rm=TRUE)
DATA
#  N_l  S  OH  e_1  e_2  e_3   e_4 e_5 e_sum
#1   3  9 3.6 14.6  2.6 -9.4    NA  NA   7.8
#2   3  9 3.6 14.6  2.6 -9.4    NA  NA   7.8
#3   4 12 4.8 21.8  9.8 -2.2 -14.2  NA  15.2
#4   4 12 4.8 21.8  9.8 -2.2 -14.2  NA  15.2
#5   4 12 4.8 21.8  9.8 -2.2 -14.2  NA  15.2
#6   5 15 6.0 29.0 17.0  5.0  -7.0 -19  25.0
#7   5 15 6.0 29.0 17.0  5.0  -7.0 -19  25.0
```

or use `apply` with `[<-` and `seq_len`

```
DATA[4:8] <- t(apply(DATA[c(1,4:8)], 1, function(x)
  "[<-"(x[-1], -seq_len(x[1]), NA)))
```

Comment: small tip, in `DATA[c(4:8)]` there is no need to the `c()`, you can simply `DATA[4:8]`

Comment: @DanielO Oh, yes. I simply have copied it form the first `DATA[c(1,4:8)]` and removed there the `1` and forgot to remove the `c`.